# Magento 2 on shared hosting, Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install'

Tags: magento2, installation, server-setup, setup

I am trying to install magento2 on shared hosting environment this is what i did.

1. Downloaded magento .zip archive and uploaded it to server in public_html/magento2 directory.

Tried running it in browser it gives me this error `"Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory."`

Same archive is working fine in my local server, i have successfully installed it on local server with sample data.

Please guide me what i am doing wrong.

**EDIT**

I have SSH access of my shared hosting, as i am on windows so i have connected that via `putty` and when i run `composer install` there it gives me this error `"-bash: composer: command not found"`

Comment: Composer must be install on your hosting. Please check there is composer installed or not.

Comment: Well, how do i check that, if that is installed or not.?
I have SSH access of my shared hosting, now when i run `"composer install"` there via ssh it gives me this error `"-bash: composer: command not found"`

Comment: You have to first install composer on server.

Comment: `Shared hosing environments does allow anything to be installed`, they will directly point me towards `VPS` or `dedicated server`.

Comment: It must be composer install otherwise you can't setup magento-2.

Comment: Okay, let me check with them, i will get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can just download `composer` in Magento root directory and run it like `php composer.phar install` or download all locally, run composer install and upload `vendor` directory on the server.

Comment: I am on shared hosting, and i had a talk with my hosting company they are ready to install composer for me, but they are asking me where they actually install it, shall i ask them to install in in `public_html/composer` Please guide me where to install composer if i want to use magento.

Comment: composer is just php script (in phar format). You can place it in any folder.
when run, just use full path to it, like `php progect/root/composer.phar install`

Comment: my hosting company has installed composer for me in root directory, but still, when I run `php composer.phar install` it says that the extension is not enabled.

Comment: Can you provide error?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install it to your localhost, and then transfer files into your shared web server. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SSH to connect to your host IP and when logged in, run the following commands to install composer;

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

Comment: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

Comment: mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer